# Azure Pipeline Copy Selected folder

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to build an Azure Pipeline using yaml that will copy selected folders (based on parameter to the pipeline) in CopyFilesOverSSH task, each directory should copy one by one.
**ERROR** 'Unable to convert from Object to String. Value: Object'
[Azure Pipeline Copy Selective folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49A0X.png)

I also tried ${{ convertToJson(directory) }}, it's converting complete collection in json and does not help in picking object one by one.

Or Please suggest alternative where I can copy selected folder based on parameter to the azure pipeline.

```
trigger: none

parameters:
- name: directoryList
  type: object
  default:
    directoryList:
    - 'LOL-01'
    - 'LOL-02'
    - 'LOL-03'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ each directory in parameters.directoryList }}:
    - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
      displayName: 'Securely copy files to the remote machine'
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: 'ssh_10.20.21.22_service_connection'
        sourceFolder: '${{ directory }}/Components'
        contents: '**'
        targetFolder: '/home/user-dir/migration_all/${{ directory }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you need to modify the value of the parameter.

Refer to my sample:

```
parameters:
- name: directoryList
  type: object
  default:
    - 'LOL-01'
    - 'LOL-02'
    - 'LOL-03'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ each directory in parameters.directoryList }}:
    - script:  echo  ${{ directory }}
```

**Result:**

[image]

You need to remove the **directoryList** in the default value. When you add this value, the entire default value will be taken as a whole.